# Diseño de base de datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

La siguiente pregunta es esta espero poder  hacer clara la pregunta

Espero hacer la pregunta de la manera correcta,supongamos que tenemos una base de datos para una cadena de hospitales y cada hospital tiene 30 tablas en donde guardan sus datos, para tener en una base de datos todos estos hospitales, ¿como se diseña la base de datos?, es una base de datos para todos las hospitales en las 16 tablas se insertan los datos de todas las farmacias  o es una base de datos para cada farmacia dentro de una base de datos global?,podrían orientarme en esto.
Cual es la forma correcta para administrar una base de datos para una empresa  que tiene los mismos datos en cada una de sus sucursales que esto podrían ser 100 sucursales.

Comment: Esta pregunta, en su formato actual, es muy amplia. Esencialmente, responderla es hacer la tarea por ti. Inténtalo y vuelve con preguntas puntuales sobre tu diseño.

Answer (score 2):

Entendiendo que hay una sola empresa que gestiona los datos de esos 100 hospitales, debe haber una sola base de datos.

Habrá una tabla maestra de hospitales con su `id_Hospital` y el resto de tablas están relacionadas con ese `id_hospital`.

**Tabla HOSPITAL**

```
id_Hospital (PK)
Nombre_Hospital
```

**Tabla FARMACIAS**

```
id_Farmacia (PK)
id_Hospital (FK) (con id_Hospital de la tabla HOSPITAL)
Nombre_Farmacia
```

**EDICION**
Los índices es algo que requiere un poco de experiencia, pero básicamente tienes de dos tipos: Los agrupados (solo puede existir uno por tabla) y los no agrupados (pueden haber varios por tabla).

Al crear una clave principal (por ejemplo id_Hospital), SQL crea un índice agrupado para esta tabla (Hospitales) y ese campo (id_Hospital). La necesidad de incorporar un nuevo índice viene, como bien dices en el comentario, de la necesidad de realizar búsquedas con mayor rapidez.

Es importante resaltar que los índices tiene beneficios (rapidez en las búsquedas) pero también tienen su lado oscuro: aumento del volumen de la base de datos y ralentización en las inserciones de nuevos datos (`INSERT`).

Por ello, si tienes muchos datos en una tabla, habrá que analizar bien las consultas que se realizan en ella (los campos del `WHERE`) y ver que campos son susceptibles de formar parte del/os índices.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios Roger Torne, no tengo mucha experiencia en SQL Server y ahora me surgió la siguiente duda, ya teniendo todos estos datos un id para cada hospital en la tabla, en estos casos se crean indices apartar del id hospital para que las búsquedas sean mas rápidas ya que tendremos miles de datos de cada hospital de forma aleatoria insertados en la tabla.

Comment: Ivan, he ampliado la respuesta para contarte lo de los índices.

Comment: Hola. Por favor, no edites la pregunta para responder.